# Distinct words sentiment analysis

Tags: python

I try to do a sentiment analysis based on a dictonary of 7000 words. The code works in Python, but it select all the combinations instead of distinct words.

For example, the dictionary says `enter` and the text says `enterprise`. How can I change the code that it doesn't see this as a match?

```
dictfile = sys.argv[1]
textfile = sys.argv[2]

a = open(textfile)
text = string.split( a.read() )
a.close()

a = open(dictfile)
lines = a.readlines()
a.close()

dic = {}
scores = {}

current_category = "Default"
scores[current_category] = 0

for line in lines:
   if line[0:2] == '>>':
       current_category = string.strip( line[2:] )
       scores[current_category] = 0
   else:
       line = line.strip()
       if len(line) > 0:
           pattern = re.compile(line, re.IGNORECASE)
           dic[pattern] = current_category

for token in text:
   for pattern in dic.keys():
       if pattern.match( token ):
           categ = dic[pattern]
           scores[categ] = scores[categ] + 1

for key in scores.keys():
   print key, ":", scores[key]
```

Comment: If your dictionary contains *words*, why using re then? Why not `if line == token`?

Comment: Thank you for your anwser Robin Koch. The problem is that the dictionary comes from a separated file. We can't include separated terms inside the file do the fact we are measuring emotions. We're not doing a word count. Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm still not sure what you match against what. Do can you provide some examples? If you really do `re.compile('enter').match('entprise')` you don't need regular expressions. If your dictionary actually contains regexps, than you should add that to the question.

Comment: what i'm doing is, that i created a separed text file that contains the emotions. each emotion contains an amount of words that are linked to the emotion. for example: the emotion happy contains the words; smile, laugh, puppy, pretty, sunshine and so on. but there are also other different emotions that contain words. so when the python script gets compiled it runs through a text. the result can be as followed; happy: 4 sad: 1 angry: 2 and so on. the problem now is that a couple of words are not detected as one word. for example: sun gets counted also if in the text the word sunshine comes up.

Comment: So you *do* a word count. Just with words falling in categories. You don't need (7000) regular expressions for that.

Comment: For this study we need 7000 expressions. So is there a way to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

`.match()` matches from the beginning of the line. So you can use an end of line anchor in your reg ex:

```
re.compile(line + '$')
```

Or you could use word boundaries:

```
re.compile('\b' + line + '\b')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your indention is incoherent. Some levels use 3 spaces, some use 4 spaces.
2. You try to match every word on your text against all 7000 words in your dictionary. Instead just look up the word in your dictionary. If it's not there, ignore the error (EAFP-principle).
3. Also I'm not sure if there is any advantage of using class methods (`string.split()`) over objects methods (`"".split()`).
4. Python also has a `defaultdict` which initializes a dictionary with 0 by itself.

EDIT:

5. Instead of `.readlines()` I use `.read()`and `.split('\n')`. This gets rid of the newline characters.
6. Splitting the text not at the default space character but on the regexp  `'\W+'` (everything that's *not* a "word character") is my attempt to get rid of punctuation.

Below my proposed code:

```py
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

dictfile = sys.argv[1]
textfile = sys.argv[2]

with open(textfile) as f:
    text = f.read()

with open(dictfile) as f:
    lines = f.read()

categories = {}
scores = defaultdict(int)

current_category = "Default"
scores[current_category] = 0

for line in lines.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith('>>'):
        current_category = line.strip('>')
    else:
        keyword = line.strip()
        if keyword:
            categories[keyword] = current_category

for word in re.split('\W+', text):
    try:
        scores[categories[word]] += 1
    except KeyError:
        # no in dictionary
        pass

for keyword in scores.keys():
    print("{}: {}".format(keyword, scores[keyword]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your code Robin but unfortunately it only count all the words. Maybe I explained it in a wrong way so I try to make it clear:
-I have on .txt dictionary -In this dictionary are 8 different emotions with words that are linked to this emotions. -I have a text which I want to check on the words from the dictionary. -In the text stands the word feeling, at this moment the code give a match when the word feel is in the dictionary (part of feeling). The purpose is that it only give a match when the exact word is in the dictionary. I hope I made it clear now?

Comment: The code does the exact same thing yours does. Counting words and add them up for each category. But I don't use `.match()` but compare the words directly to each other. - Please provide sample files from which one can see the difference you think believe to see.

Comment: This are the files. In the idtext file stand 'wantrouwen'. When you run the script and you use the dictionary I attached with only the word 'trouwen' it shouldn't match.

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c2d8c16a51a23b7f5cf1054fa58aaf0c20161206152927/d30efac816e85a3d9dc3358720d5b61420161206152927/350a6a

Comment: There was a typo in my code. `scores[dic[key]] += 1` was supposed to be `scores[dic[token]] += 1. I corrected that and used more meaningful variable names. I also fixed some issues with line breaks and punctuation. I hope it gives you to starting point to develop it further.

Comment: Great it works perfect now! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to [accept that answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419).